# Shiny reactive feature not working from one day to another

Tags: r, shiny

I am very new to stackoverflow and fairly new to R shiny so thanks for helping me with my question.

I wrote a shiny app which is running on a Linux server. Everything was working fine but without any changes to the ui or server call two parts of the app suddenly stopped working:

- Clicking the "More" tab no longer works
- Choosing an option in the "Download Center" does not show the dataset and the download button does not work either

I've restarted the app several times and checked that all packages are properly installed but nothing changed. I also get no error messages whatsoever and there is no error log in /var/log/shiny-server.

Here is my code:

```
ui <- navbarPage("My App",
tabPanel("Welcome",
         includeHTML("rmd_files/03_welcome.html")
         ),
tabPanel("Download Center",
         fluidRow(
           column(width = 6,
                  h1("Download Center"),
                  p("In this area you can find our Download Center."),
                  p("Select the dataset you are interested in on the left and a description as well as a preview will appear below."),
                  p("You can also download any dataset as a csv to explore it further.")
                  ),
           column(width = 6,
                  # move column down by 20px
                  style = "top: 20px;",
                  # Input: Choose dataset
                  selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                              choices = c("Choose...",
                                          "TestA",
                                          "TestB",
                                          "TestC"
                                          )),
                  # Button: Download data
                  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download CSV")
                  )
         ),
         hr(),
         h4("Dataset description"),
         textOutput("desc_dc"),
         hr(),
         tableOutput("table_dc")
         ),
navbarMenu("More",
           tabPanel("Presentations",
                    p("under construction")
                    ),
           tabPanel("Feature Assessment",
                    p("under construction"),
                    p("Example: ...")
           )
           )
)

##### Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {

# Download Center: Reactive output for selected dataset
dc_dataset <- reactive({
switch(input$dataset,
       "TestA" = testa,
       "TestB" = testb,
       "TestC" = testc
       )
})

# Download Center: Table of selected dataset
output$table_dc <- renderTable({
dc_dataset()
})

# Download Center: Downloadable csv of selected dataset
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
filename = function() {
  paste(input$dataset, "_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
},
content = function(file) {
  write.csv(dc_dataset(), file, row.names = FALSE)
}
)

# Download Center: Reactive output for selected dataset  
dc_description <- reactive({
switch(input$dataset,
       "TestA" = testa_desc,
       "TestB" = testb_desc,
       "TestC" = testc_desc
       )
})

# Download Center: Dataset descriptions
output$desc_dc <- renderText({
dc_description()
})

}


# Create Shiny app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can you spot something of have another idea what might help? Could it have something to do with my R version, Linux etc?

```
>system('shiny-server --version', intern = TRUE)
[1] "Shiny Server v1.5.7.907" "Node.js v8.10.0"

>R --version
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

>cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
```

Comment: Just in case someone else has the same problem: Apparently the html of some Rmd files I am including in the app interfered with other features working properly. I solved it by including those htmls in iFrames which solved the problem. I'm not super happy with it but at least now the whole app works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else has the same problem: Apparently the html of some Rmd files I am including in the app interfered with other features working properly. I solved it by including those htmls in iFrames which solved the problem. I'm not super happy with it but at least now the whole app works again.